# LINQ entity results to List<string>

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, linq, casting

I have a query which returns only a column from an entity in silverlight4 domainservice. How do I cast the results into a List?

```
public List<string> GetDataForTags() 
{
    var result =  from d in this.ObjectContext.vwBusinessUnits
                  select d.BusinessLineID.Distinct();
    return result;
}
```

I try using

```
return result as List<ToList();
```

and

```
return result.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

but I get a cannot implicitly convert type error from `Generic.IEnumerable<string>` to `Generic.List<string>`

Currently I'm able to convert using

```
 var result =  from d in this.ObjectContext.vwBusinessUnits
                         select d.BusinessLineID;
            return result.Distinct().ToList();
```

I am trying to use this result in the view model but am getting a conversion error

```
 private void LoadBUGroupTags()
    {
        TagsData = SecurityDomainContext.Current.GetDataForTags();
    }
```

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.InvokeOperation>'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

and TagsData is just a public property

```
public List<string> TagsData 
        {
            get 
            {
                return _tags;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_tags != value)
                {
                    _tags = value;
                 OnNotifyPropertyChanged("TagsData");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not really clear what the types involved are - but `d.BusinessLineID` is a string, then you're ending up with an `IQueryable<IEnumerable<char>>` which isn't what you want.

I *suspect* you want:

```
var result =  from d in this.ObjectContext.vwBusinessUnits
              select d.BusinessLineID;
return result.Distinct().ToList();
```

That's more simply written (IMO) without the query expression:

```
return this.ObjectContext.vwBusinessUnits
           .Select(d => d.BusinessLineID)
           .Distinct()
           .ToList();
```

Comment: @dknaack: Not quite back yet - waiting at Cleveland airport. And yes, I recorded a podcast with Scott. Saw the tweet, but figured that if you've accepted an answer already, you're happy - let me know if that's not the case.

Comment: I still get an implicitly convert type error from Generic IEnumerable<string>> to Generic.List<string>.
 List<string> Temp = SecurityDomainContext.Current.GetDataForTags();

Comment: @stevenjmyu: Where exactly are you getting that error? If it's at the *calling* code, are you *sure* that `GetDataForTags` is really declared as returning `List<string>` rather than `IEnumerable<string>`? It would help if you'd include the full error (with cut and paste - it looks like you've just retyped the error at the moment, with some mistakes) including the line it points at.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) method. This takes the IEnumerable which is essentially what var is and will put it to a list. There is also a ToArray method (FYI).

EDIT:

The other option is to create a new list passing in the var variable. [Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
  var result =  (from d in this.ObjectContext.vwBusinessUnits 
                select d.BusinessLineID).Distinct().ToList(); 

   return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the result as a List of strings you should convert the Business line to a string before getting the list:

```
var result = this.ObjectContext.vwBusinessUnits.Select(x=>x.BusinessLineID.ToString()).Distinct();
```

After done this you can get the result as string

```
var resultList = result.ToList();
```